# Any way to ensure that no more than x HTTP requests are sent to a certain site in Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, networking, alpine-linux

I am using Docker, base image is alpine. I have an application that sends HTTP GETs to a certain site but I have a limitation, after 50 requests I have to pay some amount per request and I want to avoid that.
I will also impose some sort of hard stop from the application code but I wanted to know if there is some way of also doing this from Linux, just in case.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the Linux Operating System level, the blocking of outbound requests can be done in these 3 ways:

1. ***iptables***  outbound rule

> iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j DROP

2. **Linux Traffic Controller (tc)**

> More information:
>
> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html
>
> https://netbeez.net/blog/how-to-use-the-linux-traffic-control/

3. ***Application proxy (squid or cuttle)***

> More information:
>
> https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-limit-bandwidth-squid
>
> https://github.com/mrkschan/cuttle